# ¿Como mandar ejecutar una función de JS de forma asíncrona para evitar se "congele" una imagen de "cargando"?

Tags: ajax

Tengo una función que antes de ser "disparada" intenta mostrar en una pagina web un imagen GIF animada de "cargando" para que una vez que terminen todas las instrucciones de la función por último esa imagen se desaparezca, ¿Cuál es el problema", el problema es que una de las instrucciones de esta función manda ejecutar una instruccion de Jquery AJAX de forma NO asincrona lo que provoca que se ejecute como si fuera una instrucción normal (es decir la línea se ejecuta y hasta que no termine no puede comenzar la siguiente instrucción de código), de hecho dentro de la función se ejecutan varios AJAX no asíncronos, lo que sucede aquí es que cuando hay una imagen con movimiento GIF, está se "congela" o no se "muestra" cuando hay funciones no asincronas, si estas funciones fueran asíncronas entonces la imagen se ve claramente con su movimiento, pero en este caso NO PUEDO modificar que sean síncronas, pues debo esperar su resultado, el ejemplo es así:

```js
        funcion agregarTallas()
        {
        $('#imagen').show();
        $.ajax({
                      url: 'agregarUsuarioATallas.php?'+gets,  //server script to process data
                      type: 'GET',
                      async: false,
                  //Ajax events

                      success: function(data)
                  { 
                    //alert('jamon:'+data);
                    IDNuevoUsuariosPrendas=data.trim();  
                      },
                      error: function(data){
                        alert('error, JS no pudo ejecutar el archivo agregaUsuario.php');

                      },
              }); 
         $('#imagen').hide();
        }
```

Entonces pienso que una forma de solucionar que si se pueda ver la imagen con su movimiento hasta que la función termine sería poder disparar toda esta función desde OTRA de manera asíncrona para que la imagen NO SE PASME.
En otras palabras ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar una funcion de JS de forma asíncrona? o bien como lograr que la imagen no se vea "pasmada" o que si se vea antes de poder ejecutar la función. Espero darme a entender. Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo por el que quieres que la petición no sea asíncrona: `async: false`?  Puedes hacerla asíncrona, y dentro del `success` ocultar la imagen con:`$('#imagen').hide();`

Comment: La función debe ser no asincrona ya que esta en realidad se dispara dentro de un ciclo FOR varias veces y si la mando ejecutar libremente se acumulan muchos hilos de ejecución dando quizas una saturación de memoria en el servidor de todas las peticiones, cada una de ellas lo que hace es insertar un registro en una base de datos, y desconozco que va a pasar si las dejo libres..osea asincronas..

Comment: Entiendo, pero me pregunto si no deberías repensar la lógica de tu programa ¿?  No es normal mandar peticiones de ese tipo al servidor a mansalva. ¿Seguro que hay que hacerlo así? ¿No se puede hacer de otro modo?

Comment: Pues la otra es mandar todos los datos de un solo fregadazo a una sola funcion asincrona resultando más complicado la separación de datos en el PHP que recibe los mismos, por eso pensé que quizás había otra forma de ejecutar toda la función de manera asincrona...

Comment: A ver, ¿cuando hablas de *todos los datos* te refieres a cientos de miles o millones de datos? Si es así te daría la razón en que no se deberían enviar todos esos datos de golpe, pero si hablamos de decenas, centenas o miles de datos, es mucho menos costoso enviarlos todos juntos que enviarlos uno por uno. Cada vez que haces una petición Ajax al servidor hay un consumo de recursos, es como enviar mercancía, ¿mandarías 50 vehículos cada uno con un producto o enviarías un camión con los 50 productos? Plantéate el asunto en términos reales y evalúa lo que sea mejor.

Answer (score 0):

En stackOF en inglés encontré que esto se debe a que el hilo que maneja la aplicación JS no permite el refresh del browser.
Para evitar que no aparezca tu imagen, aunque algunas veces va a aparecer y desaparecer tan rápido que no lo veas dependiendo del tiempo que tomen tus servicios en contestar, usa

```
windows.focus();  luego de activar el .show()
```

Te recomiendo no usar el gif por servicios, sino por todo el paquete. Es decir que prende tu gif antes de hacer todas las llamadas y apágalo cuando termine.

Puedes revisar la pregunta en 
[DOM refresh on long running function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876394/dom-refresh-on-long-running-function/16876499#16876499)

Comment: Por favor agrega el enlace a la respuesta original, para darle los créditos al autor del aporte

Comment: Lo que quiero es que SI aparezca la imagen y se vea su movimiento

Comment: Así funcionará, pon el windows.focus() en seguida el image.show() y la verás, aunque siga el código que bloquea el hilo.